# $\mathcal{O}_K$ UFD $\iff h_K=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

How can we prove that, if $K$ is a number field, then his integer ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ is an unique factorization domain if and only if the class number of $K$ is 1?

Comment: One direction is easy; have you figured out which one it is?

Comment: If $h_K=1$, then every fractional ideal is principal. In particular, every "integer" ideal of $\mathcal{O}_k$ is principal, so $\mathcal{O}_k$ is PID $\Rightarrow$ UFD

Comment: On the other side, if $\mathcal{O}_K$ is an UFD, then is a PID (it is a Dedekind ring), so every "integer ideal" is principal. Does it implies that every fractional ideal is principal?

Comment: Since every fractional ideal can be written as a product of prime ideals (with possible negative exponents), and the primes are principal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider these:

- The ideals of $\mathcal{O}_K$ have unique factorization into prime ideals.
- The class number of $K$ is $1$ iff every ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is principal.

Answer (score 0):

For Dedekind rings PID and UFD is equivalent. Since the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of a number field $K$ is a Dedekind ring, it follows that UFD is the same as PID for it, i.e., the same as class number $1$.